# Maximum surface charge of grounded plate

Tags: electric-fields

If I have a conductive plate within an electric field the max surface charge is calculated as:
$$Q_{max} = \frac{Vk\epsilon_0A}{d}$$

Where $V$ = Voltage, $k$ = dielectric constant, $\epsilon_0$ = permittivity of free space, $A$ = Area of plate and $d$ = distance between plates.

If this plate is grounded the charge $Q_{max}$ will flow to the ground in order to ensure that the plate and ground are at the same potential. If this electric field is constant would there be a continuous flow of charge $Q_{max}$ to the ground?

If not, how much charge would flow to the ground and is there an equation that relates the size of the plate and the charge that would flow to the ground if it wasn't $Q_{max}$?

Edit - I have found the answer to the majority of the question from this link [Charge distribution on plates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108231/charge-distribution-on-plates)

I believe there would only be a flow once there is no charge on the outer plates to ensure equilibrium and the equation that relates the size of the plate and the charge is just the original max surface charge described above.

Comment: Where are you getting that expression for max surface charge? That's typically an expression for the charge on the two _charged_ plates that are _generating_ the field, not for a neutral conductive plate in the middle.

Comment: Is there an expression for max surface charge for a grounded neutral conductive plate within the electric field?